# Elasticsearch Cluster sync with kafka

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect, elasticsearch-5

I have a cluster of Elasticsearch 5.6 and I want to get backup data from my cluster. can I use Kafka-connector and join two Elasticsearch cluster together? which mean that sync all data of main cluster to backup cluster!

Comment: Do you mean HA by backup?

Comment: You can add date field added in the source cluster like : updatedAt and on destination cluster, run a `cron` job every hour/minutes as per the requirement, which can sync data between clusters. In short, You can use `_reindex` API.